# how to properly load the files(including models) in my Google Drive via Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to read my files in my Google drive via Google colab and redirect it to my project.

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/")
!ls
```

It seems the path is right.

```
 2D       loss_test.py     Run.ipynb           'train from scratch'
 Base_Model.py    model.py    'saved models'       'try out codes.py'
 checkpoints      Plot.py      Siamese_Gan.py      'try read text.py'
'fine tune'   __pycache__      Siamese_Network.py
 Fine_Tuning.py  'raw evalaute'   'split data'
 loss.py      read_Images.py   test.py
```

But if I run the code to read files (which works fine on my own computer), it still can't find the directory.

```
!python read_Images.py  #program to read files
```

```
2020-06-13 12:56:45.621514: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_Images.py", line 124, in <module>
    train_imgs, train_l, val_imgs, val_l = create_data.split_data(3000, 200)
  File "read_Images.py", line 80, in split_data
    all_images, all_labels = self.images_patches()
  File "read_Images.py", line 55, in images_patches
    data, labels = self.read_images(self.name)
  File "read_Images.py", line 39, in read_images
    with open(txt_path, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as t:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2D\\CarboKlev\\1\\CarboKlev_1_OriValues.txt'
```

I attach a PrtSc for better understanding. Why is this happening?[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I find where the problem is.
It turns off if I use `matplotlib.image.imread()` in Google Colab it only supports `/` in the path and `\\` is not supported, which I don't know why.